# Require multiple entries for "Item", Django Admin

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I want to enter multiple entries for "item" under one "session_title" - and I think I understand I need a ManyToOne relationship (set with ForeignKey) but mysite/admin isn't showing multiple entries available? I am using DjangoAdmin to administer my app.

Edit/Add: I know there's a step I'm missing. I'm hoping for someone to send me there.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.TextField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'item'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

class SessionLog(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    session_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    campaign = models.OneToOneField(Campaign, models.DO_NOTHING, default="1")
    chapter = models.OneToOneField(Chapter, models.DO_NOTHING, default="1")
    scene = models.OneToOneField(Scene, models.DO_NOTHING, default="1")
    character = models.OneToOneField(Character, models.DO_NOTHING, default="1")
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    npc = models.OneToOneField(Npc, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    monster = models.OneToOneField(Monster, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    loot_pp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loot_gp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loot_ep = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loot_sp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loot_cp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_xp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_strongstart = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_secrets = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_clues = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'session_log'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.session_title
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're on the right track.

Change

```
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

to

```
items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

and in your admin, [declare an Inline class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models):

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    pass

class SessionLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ItemInline]
```

Comment: You. Are. Awesome. !!!!! it took a few tries (the models.py didn't like having on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING after changing to ManyToManyField) and figuring out where to place what you said to add to the admin.py. BUT IT WORKS!!! Thank you! Can I ask you another question?!

Comment: Glad I could help! Sure, though it may take a while to reply.

Comment: Been reading up on this and can't quite figure out WHICH files to edit to make it work. I am using DaemonMode. https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ReloadingSourceCode.wiki

Comment: In 2020 you'll be happier off with, say, Nginx and Gunicorn to run your app.